# Where can I learn the jargon of the Diablo 3 community?

Tags: diablo-iii, terminology

I have played Diablo 3 a few times. Always just "offline" with my own heros. Recently I started again and noticed (again actually) those messages from other users.

Alas, the flawed English in use isn't the only problem, but also the jargon that seems to be used.

For example:

- "lf t16 bounties"
- "lfm"

But there are more, it's just that the chat history doesn't go back quite that far. For example I *think* that "dh" in one message referred to "demon hunter", but I cannot be certain.

Anyway, my question is where I can learn about this sort of jargon (or acronyms?) in order to participate with the *online* community as well.

Comment: Honestly, in Diablo 3 you don't have to talk to people. The only thing you need to communicate is if you found bandit shrine, rainbow/treasure portal or "gob" (manager gob or many gob ;), just type that into party chat, otherwise your party member may get upset. You can't trade in Diablo 3 and I am not even sure if there is a public chat with "lfg" stuff, matchmaking makes group finding experience very satisfying. Make sure to choose proper game type when creating/joining public games. Many people don't even speak english (I often met french).

Comment: https://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/30729-diablo-iii-urban-dictionary

Comment: There is indeed a public chat with lfg stuff, which is what 'lf t16 bounties' refers to

Answer (score 10):

The Diablo wiki contains a page dedicated to terms and acronyms of Diablo III. [The page can be viewed here.](https://www.diablowiki.net/Reference)

> An uber list of abbreviations, acronyms, and other terms specifically related to Diablo III. To streamline it, this list has been purged of general online chat acronyms and terms. Those can be found in the Diablo 2 version of this list elsewhere in this wiki.
>
> Most of the key terms on this page are linked to articles that explain them in greater detail.
>
> See the [Diablo Glossary](https://www.diablowiki.net/Glossary) for a concise list of common Diablo 3 game terms/concepts, with links to full pages of info.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Do you happen to know what the mentioned acronyms (?) stand for. It appears they aren't on that list.

Comment: Lfm is generic, it means somebody or a group is Looking For More players for a party. T16 bounty means a Torment 16 bounty (torment is the highest difficulty in d3)

Comment: Anything missing from that list would probably be generic acronyms used in most games/MMOs. So try and look for a list of those, perhaps. (LFG is Looking For Group, WTT-WTB-WTS = Want To Trade-Buy-Sell, etc)

Comment: @0xC0000022L Just in case you still need more info.. bounties is the game mode beside the campaign. You might also see 'grifts' which means greater rifts. Mobs means groups of enemies, usually associated with a color which corresponds to the color of the name of the enemy. DH is demon hunter like you though. Let me know if you see any others you need help with - I've played d3 since launch so I've seen most of them.

Comment: Many of the acronyms you (@0xC0000022L) are referencing are somewhat common in mmo type games. As I assume you are not a native English speaker, you could probably find many of these references looking up more "common" mmos (massively-multiplayer online games), such as WOW, or from my personal experience, LOTRO/SWTOR.

Comment: @Asinine alright, that's good advice. Thanks. And yes, I am a non-native speaker of English.

Answer (score 3):

**1337 5p34k**

"[leet speak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)" has a long history of being used in Blizzard games (and others as well).

The language itself is rather all encompassing, since it is not technically defined.

Some more straightforward ones you may come across in chat for Diablo 3 are

- LFM : Looking for more
- WTT : Want to trade
- WTS : Want to sell
- WTB : Want to buy
- KW : Keywarden
- A1-A5 : Act 1 through Act5
- GR : Greater Rift
- T1-T16 : Torment 1 through Torment 16
- TP : Town Portal

At this point, there really aren't numbers being used as letters anymore since all the OG h8x0rz have moved on to real jobs. Most of the abbreviations you will now encounter are rather straightforward acronyms. If it seems to match, then it is probably what you are thinking. DH... Demon Hunter... Not rocket science :)

Some of the less straightforward ones are more historical, such as

- mob : an enemy or group of enemies
- aggro : to have a mob notice you and begin pathing towards you or attacking you
- kite : to make an aggro'd mob follow you somewhere
- speedrun : to skip all mobs / goals aside from the target mob / goal
- loot / drops : an item in the game
- spec / build : your character's talent choices
- tank : a character built for taking as much damage as possible
- tanking : to occupy a mob or to be in charge of aggroing mobs
- glass canon : a character built with no defense and pure offense
- op : "over powered", to be far stronger than the expected level for that area
- sherpa : to take an OP character and help other characters get better loot
- carry : to do all the work
- power level : to have a much stronger (op) character take a much lower level character through high level content in order to level them faster
- mule : a level 1 character which is used only for extra storage of loot

Comment: Acronyms aren't exactly leet speak. Being a reverse code engineer I am no stranger to leet speak and the hacker culture.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - I wasn't trying to insinuate that, just pointing out that is kind of where this came from, and where it ended up is in this simple form. It's true, acronym use isn't exactly leet speak, but the prevalence of use is a remnant of times when leet speak was used with much more frequency. Nowadays, it just tends to be a simpler version, with less counter intuition involved.

Comment: I'm not sure the two are really connected at all. Leet speak doesn't generally have brevity as a goal (in fact, it often goes out of the way to be inconvenient to type), which is the main purpose of these abbreviations, and you see the same phenomenon in a lot of other communication systems that have nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: It got watered down over time, however, you can see brevity littered throughout leetspeak. n00b, pwnd, w00t, etc. are all common "leet" derived words (leet itself coming as a truncation as well).

Comment: In online gaming communities, jargon now mostly resides in well known acronyms which relate to either a meme, in game meta, lore, or definition. As texting became more popular, it became more and more common to see users introducing brevity as opposed to being witty. Older jargon tends to be more descriptive.

Comment: @TravisJ I understand. Just wanted to get my point of view across. For obvious reasons I did upvote despite my disagreement in that aspect ;)

Comment: @0xC0000022L - I updated this to include some non acronym-ish terms to hopefully show that this isn't *just* acronyms being used in the jargon.